# Why is my icon not centered in the svg preview?

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

I try to make custom icons for an app. I use **Illustrator** to create compound paths. Therefore I use **FontAwesome-Pro.5.13.0** icons. When I export my custom icons in SVG format they seem to have a different padding (see the picture below). Left is the exported icon which has the same compound path as the right one. The only difference is that I exported the FontAwesome to svg.

[image]

Anyone got an idea what's happening?